# Problem 3 chapter 5 from baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose $g$ is a real function on $\mathbb{R}^1$, with bounded derivative (say $|g'|\leqslant M$). Fix $\varepsilon>0$, and define $f(x)=x+\varepsilon g(x)$. Prove that $f$ is one-to-one if $\varepsilon$ is small enough.

**Proof:**

Let $x\neq y$ namely $x<y$. Then $$f(y)-f(x)=y+\varepsilon g(y)-(x+\varepsilon g(x))=(y-x)+\varepsilon(g(y)-g(x))=$$ Since our function $g$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^1$ then by mean value theorem $\exists \theta\in (x,y)$ such that $g(y)-g(x)=(y-x)g'(\theta)$. Hence we get: $$=(y-x)+\varepsilon(y-x)g'(\theta)=(y-x)\left[1+\varepsilon g'(\theta)\right].$$ Hence $$|f(y)-f(x)|=(y-x)|1+\varepsilon g'(\theta)|\geqslant (y-x)(1-\varepsilon |g'(\theta)|)\geqslant (y-x)(1-\varepsilon M).$$ Taking $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2M}$ we get $|f(y)-f(x)|\geqslant \frac{1}{2}(y-x)>0.$

Sorry if topic is repeated but can anyone check this proof?
Is my proof correct?

Comment: I got $|f(y)-f(x)|>0$ then $f(y)\neq f(x)$. Thus if $x\neq y$ then $f(y)\neq f(x)$. It's a definition of one-to-one mapping (or injective function).

Comment: Looks good, though, generally, "$\varepsilon$ is small enough" can mean "for all $\varepsilon<\varepsilon_0$". But that's easy to fix.

Comment: @QuangHoang, I can't understand you. You think that above solution has some problems? I showed that for any $M$ exists $\varepsilon=\varepsilon_M$ such that $f$ is one-to-one.

Comment: The solution is OK. It can be improved by showing that there is $\varepsilon_0$ so that $f$ is injective for **any** $\varepsilon<\varepsilon_0$. That's what "small enough" usually means to me.

Comment: I think the proof is fine. It's clear from the proof that any $0 < \epsilon < 1/M$ will work.

Comment: @QuangHoang, Can I ask you one question? What means that some statement hold if $\varepsilon$ is small enough?

Comment: It means what I said: statement holds for $\varepsilon<\varepsilon_0$. For example, in the definition of limit, we usually say "$a_n$ is closed to $L$ when $n$ is large enough" or "$f(x)$ is close to $f(y)$ when $x$ is close enough to $y$". What you proved above is usually stated as "there exists an $\varepsilon$ so that $f$ is injective" as oppose to "$\varepsilon$ is small enough".

Comment: @QuangHoang, Great answer! So it means that exists some $\varepsilon_0$ such that for any $\varepsilon<\varepsilon_0$ we have what we need. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is fine. But note that we neither need the differentiability of $g$, nor that $|g'(x)|\leq M$. You just have used that $g$ is $M$-Lipschitz, and the triangle inequality: From
$$f(y)-f(x)=\bigl(y+\epsilon g(y))-\bigl(x+\epsilon g(x)\bigr)=y-x+\epsilon\bigl(g(y)-g(x)\bigr)$$
we obtain
$$|f(y)-f(x)|\geq |y-x|-\epsilon|g(y)-g(x)|\geq(1-\epsilon M)|y-x|\ .$$
It follows that $f$ is injective as soon as $\epsilon M<1$.